# Access a Windows Proxy server through Debian/Ubuntu

Tags: windows, internet, debian, proxy, authentication

I am trying to access the Internet from a Debian server using a Windows Proxy server which requires authentication. I have tried using this command in the /etc/bash/bashrc file, but it still doesn't seem to work, any ideas?

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://user:pass@ipaddress:port
```

Comment: Does the Windows proxy support HTTP authentication, or does it require NTLM?

Comment: Apparently it's HTTP, would that make a big difference then?

Comment: No, NTLM is the more complicated authentication method so you should be good to go.

Comment: Apparently the the Windows Proxy server is not seeing a request from this machine when trying 'sudo aptitude update', although it can see 'telnet ipaddress port'. Useful?

Comment: When you say access, do you mean using a web browser, or are you issuing a `apt-get update`, or what?

Comment: using apt-get update, there's no gui installed

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to get apt-get update to work, try putting the following in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxy`:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://domain\username:password@proxy:8080";
```

That won't work for anything other than apt, but if you're just trying to do updates, that should work.

Answer (score 0):

you could try after encapsulating the http://user:pass@ip:port within single quotes, as reasoned [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-bash.html).

Comment: Ok, updated as such:
export HTTP_PROXY='http://user:pass@ipaddress:port'

Still no luck

Comment: Tough. Also, perhaps the Windows Proxy needs to be configured to add an exception for the debian server's ip-address. Some proxies will block any unregistered ip-addresses unless specifically configured otherwise.

Comment: yeah, i've suggested this to them already, not heard back from them checking their logs as yet